# Adding a iVar to Core data entity

Tags: ios, core-data

I am utilizing core data entities to load the data in a table View.

I need some information (an instance of a  custom class which is not subclassed from NSManagedObject but subclassed from NSObject )to be added to the entity just to logically bind them at runtime. I do not need to cache the data offline.

I will not be making any changes to the data Model.

Is this a right practice?

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you don't want to change the model? If possible, you could add that property as transient. It will not stored offline but only in memory.

Comment: To complete, I think it is fine also to just add ivars, if he doesn't have to deal with iCloud. Also, iOS 5 + iCloud was quite buggy, don't know with iOS6